Unable to Import Pyomo (MIS) Minimal Intractable System finder
I am running a nonlinear optimization problem using Pyomo packages 6.7.3 and 6.7.4 with SCIP as a solver, and I would like to use the MIS tool to identify infeasible constraints. I can’t seem to import the tool. IIS will not work for me since I am not using CPLEX, Xpress, or Gurobi.

Is it already available? What can I do to make it work? (Related link)


Welcome to OR.SE. As far as I know, SCIP does not have an internal function to compute IIS like CPLEX and Gurobi do. However, this link may be related to what you are asking for.

@A.Omidi, it's a work in progress, but in PySCIPOpt we've added a get_infeasible_constraints to the recipes folder. You can see it here.

@J.Dionisio, thanks for your comments. It would be worth seeing such a great function on PySCIPopt as soon as possible. :)
